# Is an Email Service an appropriate "service" in a SOA?

Tags: email, architecture, service, soa

Does it make sense to create a service whose only responsibility is to send emails for other services?

Let me try to express my doubts more clearly and give a little bit of context. BTW, you can ignore the term "SOA" if you like. My intent in including it was to communicate that I am talking about a distributed system that is partitioned by function.

The reasons why I am uncertain as to whether an "Email Service" is appropriate or not are:

1. It provides a technical function
   rather than an organization
   function. It doesn't compose the
   email messages, it just processes
   them. Would it make sense to have
   the Email Service compose the
   messages by responding to domain
   events? Would this be beneficial or
   harmful?
2. It seems to introduce dependencies
   into all other services which
   utilize it. Particularly, I can't
   see how one could avoid RPCish
   interactions between the client and
   the Email Service. Even if you use
   messaging, the messages would be of
   the command style (telling the Email
   Service to send an email) which as I
   understand it are inappropriate for
   communications between services
   since they increase coupling due to
   the knowledge the client has to have
   about the service it is consuming in
   order for it to tell it what to do.
   Unless of course the Email Service
   composes the messages in response to
   domain events from other services
   (see point 1).
3. It is questionable how much
   "service" it provides. In other
   words, isn't the SMTP server already
   the "Email Service"? Of course, the
   custom "Email Service" might provide
   things like queuing and parsing of
   delivery reports. How much and what
   should be in the Email Service for
   it to really be necessary?

The alternative would be to have each service within the organization be responsible for sending out it's own email messages. However, this would mean that each service would have to be dependent on the SMTP server, but is that any different from being dependent on a custom "Email Service"? It would also mean that each service would be responsible for queuing and delivery management. Is this beneficial or harmful?

In addition, the email messages are considered domain entities, meaning that the organization is interested in the messages themselves in addition to the events that initiated them and the information that they carried. This means that users will be interested in viewing the messages that were sent out within context. For example you might look at a customer's account and ask to view the messages that were sent to that customer (these messages might include: account created confirmation, order placed confirmation, order shipped notification, experience feedback request, etc.).

I apologize if my question makes certain assumptions or is unclear, but based on what I've written, can anyone suggest an approach or discuss an approach that they have taken and how it worked out? I've already looked around SO for similar questions and googled on the topic but did not find anything that really applied, but if anyone can point out any resources I would greatly appreciate it. I would also be interested in answers that point out things that I might be overlooking or misunderstanding. Any sort of discussion on the matter seems valuable to me.

Comment: When you say *service* do you mean a web-service (something that exposes a callable "remote" endpoint) or are you talking about a service in the broader sense, such as described in DDD?

Comment: I do mean it in the broader sense so I suppose you could think of it in terms of a domain service. However, the system that I'm working on is comprised of several apps which means that in order to be consumable by each of the apps it must be remote, otherwise, a local version must be included within each of the apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context.  What is a service?  Is it a **technical** resource or a **business** resource?

If you were working at a technical level, partitioning a large technical soluiton into smaller parts (separation of concerns, etc) then I'd agree that an email service might well fit into this.

If the services are business services (e.g: "customer credit check") then an email service wouldn't fit into this.

And of course there's no reason why you can have both: a "top" layer of **business** services, implemented by a (technical) solution (that is composed of various sub-systems and layers) which includes a collection of **technical** services.